# exec() não executa o comando passado

Tags: php, jar

Estou tentando utilizar a função `exec()` do PHP para executar um arquivo .jar (sei que não é uma boa prática, mas é a única solução que possuo no momento), mas não estou conseguindo obter bons resultados.

O código em questão:

```
exec(java -jar /home/sistemas/relatorios/jasper_reports/NaturatinsJasperReports/NaturatinsJasperReports.jar 'SELECT * FROM ambiental.vw_fin_fua_ato_azul WHERE id_fua = 31968408 ' '/home/sistemas/relatorios/jasper_reports/jasper/memoria_calculo_azul.jasper' '/home/sistemas/relatorios/memoria_calculo_azul.pdf' '/home/sistemas/relatorios/jasper_reports/NaturatinsJasperReports/desenvolvimento.xml', $output)
```

Executo e simplesmente recebo retorno vazio. A variável `$output` vem setada com um `Array` e nada mais. Contudo, o comando passado por parâmetro funciona perfeitamente quando executado via terminal.

Alguém tem alguma ideia a respeito?

Obrigado.

Comment: Não, nenhuma. Já até troquei os caracteres do caminho para apenas minúsculos, mas nada até agora.

Comment: Não está faltando as `"" `?

Comment: Na realidade, é passada uma variável de tipo string entre "".

Comment: o que o php log diz?

Comment: Excelente ideia, @BrunoRozendo. `Unrecognized option: -jar
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
: not founde/sistemas/relatorios/jasper_reports/naturatins_jasper_reports/naturatins_jasper_reports.jar
: not foundCT * FROM ambiental.vw_fin_fua_ato_azul WHERE id_fua = 31968408 
: not founde/sistemas/relatorios/jasper_reports/jasper/memoria_calculo_azul.jasper
: not founde/sistemas/relatorios/memoria_calculo_azul.pdf
sh: 6: /home/sistemas/relatorios/jasper_reports/naturatins_jasper_reports/desenvolvimento.xml: Permission denied`. Estou tentando resolver.

Comment: Resolvido! O primeiro problema era a permissão do arquivo XML que passo como parâmetro, o segundo era que eu quebrava o comando em linhas diferentes para facilitar a leitura. Bastou alterar as permissões do XML e unir todo o comando em uma única linha. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser a permissão do Usuário, basicamente você esta rodando o servidor web com um usuário X, então você só poderá executar programas e funções em que o usuário X tem permissões devidas.

Tente mudar as permissões do arquivo ou o usuário que o servidor utiliza.

Comment: Por via das dúvidas, dei 777 a todo o caminho. Inicialmente, havia um arquivo realmente recusando o acesso, agora, a mensagem que recebo é `Unable to access jarfile`, mas o caminho está correto.